# Unit testing an ActionFilter - correctly setting up the ActionExecutingContext

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, moq, action-filter

In a custom `ActionFilter`, I want check the attributes on the controller action that will be executed. Running through a small test application, the following works when launching the app in the asp.net development server-

```
public class CustomActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var someAttribute = filterContext.ActionDescriptor
                                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeAttribute), false)
                                    .Cast<SomeAttribute>()
                                    .SingleOrDefault();

        if (someAttribute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        // do something here
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

An action method without `SomeAttribute` throws an `ArgumentException` and conversely, an action method with `SomeAttribute` does not. So far so good.

Now I would like to set up some unit tests for the ActionFilter, but how can I set up the action method upon which the `OnActionExecuting` method should run in the unit test? Using the following code doesn't find `SomeAttribute` on the action method which will be executed. Is the test set up correctly? Have I not arranged something correctly in the test? To clarify, the test is not complete but I'm not sure what I've missed such that `someAttribute` in `OnActionExecuting` in the test is `null`

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Controller_With_SomeAttribute()
    {
        FakeController fakeController =
            new FakeController();

        ControllerContext controllerContext = 
            new ControllerContext(new Mock<HttpContextBase>().Object, 
                                  new RouteData(), 
                                  fakeController);

        var actionDescriptor = new Mock<ActionDescriptor>();
        actionDescriptor.SetupGet(x => x.ActionName).Returns("Action_With_SomeAttribute");

        ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext =
            new ActionExecutingContext(controllerContext,
                                       actionDescriptor.Object, 
                                       new RouteValueDictionary());

        CustomActionFilterAttribute customActionFilterAttribute = new CustomActionFilterAttribute ();
        customActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting(actionExecutingContext);
    }

    private class FakeController : Controller
    {
        [SomeAttribute]
        ActionResult Action_With_SomeAttribute()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Since the ActionDescriptor property of `ActionExecutingContext` is virtual, you can just `override` that and provide your own implementation of `ActionDescriptor`.

Here are two tests that verify the two branches through the current implementation of `OnActionExecuting`:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
[TestMethod]
public void OnActionExecutingWillThrowWhenSomeAttributeIsNotPresent()
{
    // Fixture setup
    var ctxStub = new Mock<ActionExecutingContext>();
    ctxStub.Setup(ctx => ctx.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeAttribute), false))
        .Returns(new object[0]);

    var sut = new CustomActionFilterAttribute();
    // Exercise system
    sut.OnActionExecuting(ctxStub.Object);
    // Verify outcome (expected exception)
    // Teardown
}

[TestMethod]
public void OnActionExecutingWillNotThrowWhenSomeAttributeIsPresent()
{
    // Fixture setup
    var ctxStub = new Mock<ActionExecutingContext>();
    ctxStub.Setup(ctx => ctx.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeAttribute), false))
        .Returns(new object[] { new SomeAttribute() });

    var sut = new CustomActionFilterAttribute();
    // Exercise system
    sut.OnActionExecuting(ctxStub.Object);
    // Verify outcome (no exception indicates success)
    // Teardown
}
```